FFmpeg-Python command too long because of drawtext
I have a FFmpeg-Python program that puts subtitles into a video, pseudocode below:
for i in range(10000):
    video= video.filter(
        'drawtext', fontfile=FONT_FILE, text=cur_string, x='(w-text_w)/2', y='(h-text_h)/2',
        fontsize=FONT_SIZE, fontcolor=FONT_COLOR, borderw=2, bordercolor=FONT_OUTLINE_COLOR,
        enable=f'between(t,{i},{i+1})')

video.output(PATH).run()

The code above gives the following error:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 206] The filename or extension is too long

My questions are:
(1) Is there anyway to check when the ffmpeg command is going to exceed the cmd length limit (8191/28878? not actually sure which one is in effect) in code?
(2) How do I fix this in code?

Based on the package filter source code, filter seems to return FilterNode object that you can get the filter string by calling _get_filter method. It's not the exact command length but you can use it to estimate if the filter command is likely to exceed the command length limit (ie checking if it's exceeds cmd length limit - 50).
I think one way way to fix the code above is to instead of running 10000 filters in one run, you should try breaking it down into multiple runs that continuously updating the output file
video = ffmpeg.input(INPUT_PATH)
video.output(OUTPUT_PATH).run()

for i in range(10000):
    video = ffmpeg.input(OUTPUT_PATH)

    video= video.filter(
        'drawtext', fontfile=FONT_FILE, text=cur_string, x='(w-text_w)/2', y='(h-text_h)/2',
        fontsize=FONT_SIZE, fontcolor=FONT_COLOR, borderw=2, bordercolor=FONT_OUTLINE_COLOR,
        enable=f'between(t,{i},{i+1})')

    video.output(OUTPUT_PATH).run()

It's not the most efficient approach but you can improve it's performance by running in batches of filter instead
video = ffmpeg.input(INPUT_PATH)
BATCH_SIZE = 100

for i in range(10000):
    if i % BATCH_SIZE == 0:
        video.output(OUTPUT_PATH).run()
        video = ffmpeg.input(OUTPUT_PATH)

    video= video.filter(
        'drawtext', fontfile=FONT_FILE, text=cur_string, x='(w-text_w)/2', y='(h-text_h)/2',
        fontsize=FONT_SIZE, fontcolor=FONT_COLOR, borderw=2, bordercolor=FONT_OUTLINE_COLOR,
        enable=f'between(t,{i},{i+1})')
    
video.output(OUTPUT_PATH).run()


Use -/filter:v option for FFmpeg v7 or -filter_script:v option for earlier versions to provide the filter graph expression from a file. Combining this with the input argument of subprocess.run(), you can use a long filtergraph without the cli command length restriction.
For example,
fg = 'looooooong filtergraph expression of yours...'
sp.run(["ffmpeg", "-i", "input.mp4", "-/filter:v", "pipe:0", "output.mp4"],
       input=fg, encoding='utf-8')

Note the FFmpeg command must say pipe:0 (- won't work).
I'm not familiar with ffmpeg-python. So please convert the above snippet as you see fit.
